# Best web control to change font size

Tags: controls, font, size

So due to elements being painted onto a canvas i need to offer the user the ability to change the font size (different resolutions etc).

are there any opinions on regarding the pros on cons of the different font size controls.

ie

1.A jquery slider 
smaller -------------|-------------larger

1. or say a number box with font size and a set button.
   Font size [10]  (SET)

or the microsoft word style of a drop down list of font size. 
-10
-13
-22
-48

or a box that displays the font size with up and down arrows 
font size[14]  (up arrow) (down arrow)

Comment: will user see font changes in real time as they adjust the slider?

Comment: Is this for the user to adjust the fonts to read? If so, I'd argue the best control is the one built into the web browser.

Comment: sadly because the site is built with flash / and canvas elements the control + scroll wheel fix doesnt do anything. Thus why i am doing this fix. I was thinking i could intercept the control + scroll wheel action but i figured if i would go through that work to implement a font resize why not give the user some affordance to let them know they can change the font size. Its a readbility issue vs being able to see everything in a limited workspace. (theres other ways to fix it but right now the font size is the best tradeoff without spending a great deal of time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

I've always been a fan of this approach. It's easy for the user to see that one decreases, the other increases. They also aren't tasked with choosing from a large variety of font sizes or fiddling with getting a slider exactly where they want it. This is essentially option 3 but with iconography that directly relates to what the user can expect upon taking the action.

Comment: pretty awesome that looks like it came from apples book reader. I totally forgot about that one. I think ill let it marinate and if i go with that ill accept this on tuesday . +1 for a novel idea i forgot about.